# What does "-vp" do in "call prorest.bat live.db live.BK -vp > Backup.txt"?

Tags: command-line, cmd, command

I'm a newbie to cmd scipts, annd just want to know What "-vp" is doing here? What's the purpose of it? I don't think it's batch-parameter of the batch (prorest.bat) being called here. Instead, it should be some kind of qualifier of cmd i think. But what would this qualifier do? Can anyone please tell me?

```
call prorest.bat d:\live.db d:\dbbackup\live.BK -vp > d:\dbbackup\Verify_Live_Backup.txt
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-vp` is indeed a parameter of `prorest.bat` as you can see by looking at the [documentation of prorest.bat](http://ingleses.datasul.com.br/blog/post/2008/11/07/Utilize-os-utilitarios-PROBKUP-e-PROREST-como-referencia-para-copiar-bancos.aspx).

> -vp: Faz a leitura do bloco de backup, calcula o CRC e compara com o bloco do banco.

Comment: (in english : reads the backup block per block, computes the CRC and compares with the reference)